# Why setting margin-left to auto moves div to right side

Tags: css, css-position

I would like to know the reason as to why setting margin-left ib the `div` with `id="pink"` to auto moves the div to right side. Pls see the image the image:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="aqua">aqua</div> 
 <div id="yellow">yellow</div> 
 <div id="pink">pink</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#aqua, #yellow, #pink { border:1px solid blue;}

#pink { width:150px;
   margin-left:auto;
 }
```

[image]

Pls check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q234tc6s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you set the `margin-left` to `auto`, the div's margins and padding are all zero width, and the borders are set to a width of 1px.

For block level elements in normal flow, the equation

```
'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' 
+ 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' 
= width of containing block
```

must hold. But with all the values set, that can't happen, and the div is said to be *over-constrained*. So the margin-right property is overridden and computed to a value that lets the equation hold. This places the div's content box on the left of the container.

When `margin-left:auto` is set, the div is no longer over-constrained, and the value of the margin-left will be computed such that the equation above holds. This leaves the content box on the right of the container.

---

<sub>As a tip, it's well worth getting your head around this equation. A whole class of CSS layout phenomena can be explained by understanding how it is applied. The full details are at https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#blockwidth</sub>

Comment: does the link info is same as this link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth . Basically what's the diff between the two pages ?

Comment: There's not necessarily any difference. CSS 2.2 is a draft incorporating changes fixing errata in CSS 2.1. Because I've been caught out in the past by missing the errata, by default I link to the CSS 2.2 draft instead these days.

Answer (score 4):

Auto tells it to fill the available space. This will be the container width minus the width of your div.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to put `#pink` center-aligned, you should set both `margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto.